# bash execute command in variable

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables, command

I have a command in a variable in Bash:

```
check_ifrunning=\`ps aux | grep "programmname" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l\`
```

The command checks if a specific program is running at the moment.
Later in my script, I want to query the value of the variable on a point.
If the specific program is running, the script should sleep for 15 minutes.

I solved it like this:

```
while [ $check_ifrunning -eq 1 ]; do
sleep 300
done
```

Will the script execute the command in the variable for each single loop-run or will the value in the variable stay after the first execution?

I have more variables in my script which can change their value. This was just one simple example of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that `check_ifrunning` is set only once, in

```
 check_ifrunning=`ps aux | grep "programmname" | grep -v "grep" | wc -l`
```

and that it is set *before* the loop:

```
 while [ $check_ifrunning -eq 1 ]; do
   sleep 300
 done
```

You could add, for debugging purposes, an `echo check_ifrunning is $check_ifrunning` statement inside your `while` loop just before the `sleep` ...

You probably simply want (using [pidof(8)](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_pidof.htm)) - *without* defining or using any `check_ifrunning` Bash *variable*:

```
 while [ -n "$(pidof programname)" ]; do
    sleep 300
 done
```

Because you want to test if `programname` is running at every start of the loop!

You should use the more nestable and more readable `$(`...`)` instead of backquotes.

Consider reading the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)...

If you are writing a Bash script, consider to start it with

```
 #!/bin/bash -vx
```

while debugging. When you are satisfied, remove the `-vx`...

Comment: First of all thank you for answer.
So I have to "re-set" the varibale everytime before a loop?
Would this be possible with a function, which I call before every loop?
As already mentioned, I have more variables like these in my script. They may change during the run of the script.

Comment: Read more about bash scripting. Use the `-vx` trick. You seems very confused about what variables are in bash....

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encapsulate your commands, the proper way to do that is a function.

```
running () {
    ps aux | grep "$1" | grep -q -v grep
}
```

With `grep -q` you get the result as the exit code, not as output; you use it simply like

```
if running "$programname"; then
    :
```

Ideally, the second `grep` is unnecessary, but I did not want to complicate the code too much. It still won't work correctly if you are looking for `grep`. The proper solution is `pidof`.

See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050